# regular expression replace for SQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have to replace a string pattern in SQL with empty string, could anyone please suggest me?

Input String `'AC001,AD001,AE001,SA001,AE002,SD001'`
Output String `'AE001,AE002`

There are the 4 digit codes with first 2 characters "alphabets" and last two are digits. This is always a 4 digit code. And I have to replace all codes except the codes starting with "AE".

I can have 0 or more instances of "AE" codes in the string. The final output should be a formatted string "separated by commas" for multiple "AE" codes as mentioned above.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Postgres manual page on regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)? It includes a `regexp_replace` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option calling regex_replace multiple times, eliminating the "not required" strings little by little in each iteration to arrive at the required output.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    'AC001,AD001,AE001,SA001,AE002,SD001', '(?<!AE)\d{3},{0,1}', 'X','g'
                ),'..X','','g'
            ),',$','','g'
        )
```

See Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2b08310723e8635ab4b46a2715501e58)

Comment: Thank you much vmaroli your solution really worked. I didn't understand the use of "{0,1} in the code. Could you please explain?

Comment: ,{0,1} is for matching zero or one coma character.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the list to an array, unnest that to rows then filter out those that should be kept and aggregate it back to a string:

```
select string_agg(t, ',')
from unnest(string_to_array('AC001,AD001,AE001,SA001,AE002,SD001',',') as x(t)
where x.t like 'AE%'; --<< only keep those
```

This is independent of the number of elements in the string and can easily be extended to support more complex conditions.

---

This is a good example why storing comma separated values in a single column is not such a good idea to begin with.